# Ant genkey task doesn't support the "saname" attribute

Tags: ant, keytool

Any idea how to add the san info in gen key tag in ant 1.9?

I am trying like below, but its not working

```
<genkey alias="tomcat" validity="3652" keystore="${keystore}"
        storepass="security" keypass="security" keyalg="RSA" sigalg="SHA256withRSA" keysize="2048"
        dname="CN=XX, OU=XX, O=XX, L=XX, ST=XX, C=X"
        *saname="SAN=IP:10.100.0.1,IP:192.168.0.1,DNS:myserver.mydomain.com,DNS:otherserver.otherdomain.com,EMAIL:name@mydomain.com,EMAIL:othename@otherdomain.com"*/>
```

The error is:

```
genkey doesn't support the "saname" attribute
```

I am using `jdk-8_261` with Ant 1.9.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an issue with Ant versions 1.9.0-1.9.13, fixed in 1.9.14.

[Ant downloads are here.](https://ant.apache.org/bindownload.cgi)

Comment: I have update to 1.9.15. and it is working file. Thanks.